# Proven research about how to minimise Continuous Partial Attention?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, attention

[Continuous Partial Attention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_partial_attention) seem to be a natural reaction to the Age of Information. However, as some authors have argued:

> it leads to a higher level of stress in the brain, prohibiting reflection, contemplation and thoughtful decisions. It also dilutes efforts to focus and concentrate on the present (effectively paying attention to what you are doing in the moment instead of shifting from one activity to another). This constant connectedness also affects real-time relationships and lowers productivity levels, leading to over-stimulation and lack of fulfillment.

These consequences are surely dreadful for individuals and society in general. Since the Age of Information is very likely here to stay, from an individual perspective, but also from educators and policy makers perspective, measures should be taken to **avoid or ameliorate such effects**.

Is there some research showing how this can be achieved? I have not found anything, but I imagine this is a very early research area.

Comment: This partial attention is often considered to be rapid switching of tasks or multitasking. Here are some related questions: https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/3708/is-multitasking-a-myth/3755#3755 , https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/15457/are-women-better-at-multitasking/15483#15483

Comment: Practical but not scientifically proven advices : 1. Create interfaces that minimize the information overload. 2. Create awareness. Inform people about this problem and its consequences. Teach people how to self-regulate the urge to process all the information presented to them, and focus only to the very few that seems important.